# Why does spaceship allow mixed comparisons (different template instantiations) with nonsense results?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

EDIT: This has nothing to do with spaceship. It is just that the use of spaceship obfuscated the real issue in my code (see answer for details).

I was surprised by the output of this [program](https://godbolt.org/z/39rGYc):
(If you like puzzles feel free to open the Godbolt link and try to spot the cause yourself)

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cassert>
#include <compare>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<typename T>
struct TotallyOrdered
{
    T val;
    constexpr TotallyOrdered(T val) :
        val(val) {}
    constexpr operator T() const { return val; }
    constexpr std::strong_ordering operator<=>(TotallyOrdered const& other) const
    {
        if (std::isnan(val) && std::isnan(other.val))
        {
            return std::strong_ordering::equal;
        }
        if (std::isnan(val))
        {
            return std::strong_ordering::less;
        }
        if (std::isnan(other.val))
        {
            return std::strong_ordering::greater;
        }
        if (val < other.val)
        {
            return std::strong_ordering::less;
        }
        else if (val == other.val)
        {
            return std::strong_ordering::equal;
        }
        else
        {
            assert(val > other.val);
            return std::strong_ordering::greater;
        }
    }
};



int main()
{
    const auto qNan = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << ((TotallyOrdered{qNan} <=> TotallyOrdered{1234.567}) ==  std::strong_ordering::less) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ((TotallyOrdered{qNan} <=> TotallyOrdered{1234.567}) ==  std::strong_ordering::equal) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ((TotallyOrdered{qNan} <=> TotallyOrdered{1234.567}) ==  std::strong_ordering::equivalent) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ((TotallyOrdered{qNan} <=> TotallyOrdered{1234.567}) ==  std::strong_ordering::greater) << std::endl;
}
```

output:

> false
> false
> false
> false

After a bit of blaming Godbolt caching... I have figured out that the problem is that I was comparing `TotallyOrdered<float>` and `TotallyOrdered<double>` (adding `f` after `1234.567` gives expected output).
My questions are:

- Why is this allowed? (Not asking if this is standard behavior; it is, but curious about design intention.)
- Why do comparisons give none of the "enums" in strong_ordering? It looks like I get a partial order when I do a mixed comparison although I have defined only `strong_order` `<=>`.
- How can I force that only "exact +-cvref" comparisons (that give a `std::strong_ordering` result) compile, preventing comparisons that give `std::partial_ordering`?

Comment: Remove `-O2` and look at the generated code in godbolt, it is quite clear what happens. Even if you don't understand asm, the "call" lines are enough.

Comment: @MarcGlisse great idea, I have not considered it, but yeah, it is all obvious now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's allowed because your conversion operator to `T` is not explicit. This allows both sides of the comparison to undergo a user-defined conversion to their respective `T`. So you end up with a `float` and a `double`. And then those can both be converted to `double` and a comparison can happen. But that comparison returns an `std::partial_ordering`, not an `std::strong_ordering`.

Note that [`std::strong_ordering`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/compare/strong_ordering) can be compared to a bool, which is why your code compiles in the first place. Although cppreference.com does note that:

> The behavior of a program that attempts to compare a strong_ordering with anything other than the integer literal ​0​ is undefined.

I'm not a 100% sure whether your program is displaying undefined behavior, or whether there's some more conversion/promotion "magic" going on.

Either way, if you change your conversion operator to be explicit, the code won't compile anymore. Which I guess is what you actually want?

Comment: I don't think I understand how the result can be a `bool`. If you compare two `double` with spaceship operator, the result should be one of the orderings, not bool.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen result is std::partial_ordering https://godbolt.org/z/oqE4ra

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Yes, and I guess the exact value is `std::partial_ordering::unordered`. I was referring to this sentence of the answer: "*But of course that comparison will give you a bool, not the enum you expect.*".  And I'm not so sure about the "*`std::strong_ordering` can be compared to a bool*" part, I can't find that in cppreference.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen You're correct, I actually missed that. Thanks! Will change my answer.

Comment: as bonus this explains why none of the couts I added in my <=> were not printing anything. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl on some IDE's (Visual Studio for example) you can hold ctrl and click the operator with mouse, and it will take you to the overload that's actually called, or will let you know that the operator isn't overloaded. If you hover, you can see the declaration like `operator<=>  (double, double)`. So, that's a good way to debug operator overload problems.